# How to get attribute value for an assembly in Cecil

Tags: c#, .net, mono, metadata, mono.cecil

Is there a way to get `str1` in code ?

```
[MyAttribute("str1")]
class X {}
```

The instance of `Mono.Cecil.CustomAttribute.Fields` is empty.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When using attributes in .NET you are either using the constructor parameters and setting some (named) fields. This is encoded differently in the metadata and ends up separately in Cecil.

> the instance of Mono.Cecil.CustomAttribute.Fields is empty

What you're using is looking for **fields** when the **constructor arguments** were used for the custom attribute. So what you're looking for is:

```
type.CustomAttributes[0].ConstructorArguments[0].Value
```

Comment: I second this magnificent answer.